# What is the difference between join and preload on Phoenix Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm confused about how to use ecto in phoenix.

My schemas are:

```
schema "members" do
    field :first_name, :string
    field :last_name, :string
    belongs_to :prefecture, Prefecture

    timestamps()
  end

  schema "prefectures" do
    field :prefecture_name, :string
    has_many :members, Member

    timestamps()
  end
```

The preload that works:

```
def list_members do
    Repo.all(Member)
      |> Repo.preload(:prefecture)
  end
```

And in templates can be used as:

```
<%= for member <- @members do %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= member.last_name %></td>
      <td><%= member.first_name %></td>
      <td><%= member.perfecture.prefecture_name %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Now when using a query it won't work:

```
def list_members do
    query = from m in Member,
            join: p in Prefecture, on: p.id == m.prefecture_id,
            select: %{last_name: m.last_name , first_name: m.first_name, prefecture_name: p.prefecture_name}
    Repo.all(query)
  end
```

In templates is used the following way:

```
<%= for member <- @members do %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= member.last_name %></td>
      <td><%= member.first_name %></td>
      <td><%= member.prefecture_name %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

It causes the following error:

```
maps cannot be converted to_param. A struct was expected, got: %{first_name: "Boo", last_name: "Muu", prefecture_name: "Japan"}
```

What is difference and what I should do for it to work?
I would like to use JOIN way. (2)

Comment: first of all make your question clear, show what the perfecture schema is and remove templates examples since they are not relevant.

Comment: Could you show the code where you're invoking `list_members`? I suppose it's in the controller before rendering the template or something like that

Comment: def index(conn, _params) do
    members = Scoresheets.list_members()

    render(conn, "index.html", members: members)
  end

Comment: I don't think the error is coming from what you shared. Are you using a URL helper? like `member_path(conn, :show, member)` or something similar? If so, please do include it in your question.

Comment: NO. I put address bar in browser. http://localhost:4000/members/

Comment: I meant in your templates. Is there a link from the members index template to the members' `:show` pages?

Comment: Yes you are right. I erased  <%= link "Show", to: Routes.member_path(@conn, :show, member) %>, then it worked!!!  What is happened?

Comment: Check the answer I've posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that it doesn't work. Like the error indicates, the problem is with the format of the result.

The result of this code:

```rb
Repo.all(Member) |> Repo.preload(:prefecture)
```

Is a list of `%Member{}` structures. Whereas the result of your other query, is a list of maps which only contain what you selected.

Hence, the error. It comes from the [URL helper](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Param.html) that you're using:

```rb
<%= link "Show", to: Routes.member_path(@conn, :show, member) %>
```

These URL helpers can build a URL from a struct, according to what they should use (id, slug, etc.). But the point is that they expect a struct. If you want to use the helper with the result from the second query, you will have to pass the id directly to the URL helper `Routes.member_path` instead of the whole `member` struct. Like:

```rb
<%= link "Show", to: Routes.member_path(@conn, :show, member.id) %>
```

For this, you will need to add the member's id to your result map in your query:

```rb
def list_members do
  query = from m in Member,
          join: p in Prefecture, on: p.id == m.prefecture_id,
          select: %{id: m.id, last_name: m.last_name , first_name: m.first_name, prefecture_name: p.prefecture_name}
  Repo.all(query)
end
```

That's if you're using the id for the URLs (e.g. `/members/:id`), if you're using something else, you'll have to use that instead.

Comment: `%{id: m.id` does not work with `<%= link "Show", to: Routes.member_path(@conn, :show, member) %>`. Is any problem?

Comment: Have you added `id` to the query as suggested in the answer? (it was added as the first item of the map) Also, is your route using the member's id?

Comment: I mean this: `select: %{id: m.id, last_name: m.last_name , first_name: m.first_name, prefecture_name: p.prefecture_name}` did you update it to include the id?

Comment: Yes. I thought if I put `%{id: m.id, `,   then `<%= link "Show", to: Routes.member_path(@conn, :show, member) %>` works. I might misunderstand.

Comment: No, no. Look at that updated part: `Routes.member_path(@conn, :show, member.id)` replacing `member` by `member.id` is the most important thing there, since if what you're passing is not a struct, the helper won't know what to use. If you use `member.id` instead, it should work

Comment: Thanks Now I understand. I need specific number.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's the id. This might help: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/routing.html#more-on-path-helpers